# Connecting webserver to VPN without creating a subnet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, webserver

I'm trying to set up a web server able to connect to a VPN and communicate with servers within the virtual network. The idea is to send data from the web server to an API that's only accessible whilst in the VPN.

Basically: WEBSERVER -> CONNECT TO VPN WITHOUT DROPPING IP -> API

Do I need two network adapters on my webserver for this to work (one connected to the VPN, the other one to the internet)? I'm not allowed to open any extra ports nor give API servers direct access to the internet.

I'm working on an Oracle Cloud VPC, where I'm also not allowed to create a public subnet.

What would be the best approach for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Frank. There is a lot that goes into this. will the website be publicly available? you will likely be able to create a point-to-site connection from the webserver to the API server's network, by creating routes to the VPN'd network at client connect. you should not need multiple nics, since most VPN clients run using a software virtual interface. you will need to enable split tunneling however,and only direct traffic for the VPN'd network to the VPN virtual adapter. DNS may be a problem, but you may be able to get by with host file hacks.

Comment: Hey there, excuse my late reply. Yes, the website would be publicly available, otherwise I would just have it in the same subnet. I'm thinking having it connect with two (virtual) network adapters is going to be the solution for now. Traffic is not going to be "redirected" per-se, the web server is handling all of it and then performing background actions in conjuction with the private API servers (in this case, just cURL POSTing info to them).

Comment: So there isn't a lot of value to using a second nic, unless you are worried about offloading traffic at the hardware level. the VPN connection is logical, so both nic's would need an Internet connection, even if one is only carrying the VPN traffic (your curl commands). when I talk about routing, I'm not talking about redirecting web traffic, but using IP routing rules to determine which interface the targets of your curl commands will be reached through (which is the VPN virtual interface), while still allowing you to respond to web traffic over the Internet.

Comment: Anyway, your question as it stands is quite broad, so you are not likely to get better answers as is. Start working on your implementation, and then ask focused and specific questions about where you are having trouble. always remember to show what you have tried, and describe clearly how it is not working for you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with oracle cloud  but from a general network point of view you should just be able to run the vpn and it should just work - provided the vpn does not publish a default gateway (or equivalent - some vpns break a default gateway into 2 routes each covering half the ip space to ensure they are more specific then the ethernet gateway).

Comment: DNS is also a common problem for this kind of configuration. a lot of orgs will address and register public DNS records for public IPs that have been fire-walled off from the Internet, just so hosts with software defined connections like VPN circuits can use public DNS servers to resolve both private and public hosts. I feel like thats wasteful, but it is one way to go.